# How to add meta fields to media using Wordpress REST API v2 by using Postman?

Tags: wordpress, postman, wordpress-rest-api

I want to be able to add meta to a media post type by using WP REST API.

I want to use Postman because, for now, I just want to test how the API is working. The docs seems to be somewhat confusing. I would be grateful if you have any working examples.

Basically, I want to add `copyright` meta field to the media using this API.

Comment: send image in base encode 64

Answer (score 1):

for creating API you need to add route first. you can add route using below code:

```
function custom_meta_api() {
register_rest_route('wp/v1', '/update_meta/(?P<id>[\d]+)', array(
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'saveMeta',
        ),
    ));
}|
add_action('rest_api_init', 'custom_meta_api');
```

you can pass your image id in `(?P<id>[\d]+)`

now in postman write url
`http://your-url/wp-json/wp/v1/update_meta/5` with POST request

in body you can write below code

```
{"data":
    {
        "copyright":"xyz"
    }
}
```

and to save in postmeta table create function saveMeta(which you have written in callback). Code for the function is below:

```
function saveMeta(WP_REST_Request $data) {
    $bookingID = $data['id'];
    $request = $data->get_json_params();
    extract($request['data']);
    update_post_meta($bookingID, 'copyright', $copyright);

    $response = array();
    $response["code"] = "success";
    $response["message"] = "";
    $response["data"] = array();
    $response["data"][] = 'meta added';

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but shouldn't there be some already existing route to do this, maybe some route that comes with WP by default?